# How to access the searched sub-fragment in a mongodb query (using Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a fairly simple collection:

```
var Access = new Schema({
  userId         : { type: ObjectId, index: true },
  token          : { type: String, index: true },
  isOwner        : { type: Boolean, index: true },
});
mongoose.model('Access', Access);

var Workspace = new Schema({
  name           : { type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true},
  description    : String,
  isActive       : Boolean,
  settings       : {
    longName        : String,
    welcomeMessage  : String,
    countryId       : { type: ObjectId, index: true },
  },
  access          : [ Access ],
});
mongoose.model('Workspace', Workspace);
```

When a user connect, I have a middleware check the token and see if everything is OK.
So, I have:

```
exports.tokenCall = function( req, res, next, token ){

  var Workspace = mongoose.model('Workspace'),
      User = mongoose.model('User'),
      accessEntry;

  req.application = {};

  // Find the token
  Workspace.findOne({ 'access.token': token } , function(err, doc){
    if(err){
      next( new g.errors.RuntimeError503( err ) );
    } else {
      if(! doc ){
        next( new g.errors.BadtokenError403() );
      } else {
        accessEntry = doc.access.filter(function(entry){ return entry.token == token;  } )[0];

        req.application.workspaceId = doc._id;
        req.application.workspaceName = doc.name;
        req.application.userId = accessEntry.userId;
        req.application.login =  accessEntry.login;
        req.application.token = token;
        req.application.workspace = doc; // Contains all of the settings!
        next();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I am sure you can see my problem here: I run `Workspace.findOne({ 'access.token': token } , function(err, doc){` to find the document with the right token. But THEN, I am actually... searching an array (!) to find the *actual* token I looked for! `accessEntry = doc.access.filter(function(entry){ return entry.token == token;  } )[0];` I am sure this is not the way to do this -- surely. What if I make a query 4 levels down...?!?

So, what is the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Mongo 2.2 you can take advantage of the new [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator to only include the matching `access` array element in the returned doc:

```
Workspace.findOne(
    { 'access.token': token }, 
    { _id: 1, name: 1, access: { $elemMatch: { token: token } } },
    function(err, doc) {
        // doc contains _id, name, and only the access array elements that match on token
```

Comment: Sweeeeeeeeeet. Using Mongo 2.2, so I should be set. Fantastic. Fantastic.